# Variable substitution in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am looking for an explanation for how the Ansible variable substitution works. I would like to have a variable as a string instead of an array.

Here is some example code:

`test.yml`

```
---

- name: Debug
  hosts: localhost
  strategy: debug
  vars:
    an_ansible_variable: 'an_ansible_variable'
    test:
      'wrong_output_with_variable': "['{{ an_ansible_variable }}']"
      'wrong_output_with_raw': "{%- raw -%}['{{ not_an_ansible_variable }}']{%- endraw -%}"
      'correct_output_with_unsafe': !unsafe "['{{ not_an_ansible_variable }}']"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test
```

output:

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test": {
        "correct_output_with_unsafe": "['{{ not_an_ansible_variable }}']", 
        "wrong_output_with_raw": [
            "{{ not_an_ansible_variable }}"
        ], 
        "wrong_output_with_variable": [
            "an_ansible_variable"
        ]
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is why the variables are arrays and not strings.

Thanks and kind regards,

Manfred

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *What I do not understand is why the variables are arrays and not strings.*

A: Because they are closed in the brackets `[]`. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    var1: var
    var2: [var]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "var1: {{ var1 }} type: {{ var1|type_debug }}"
          - "var2: {{ var2 }} type: {{ var2|type_debug }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
  - 'var1: var type: AnsibleUnicode'
  - 'var2: [''var''] type: list'
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I need the variable to be a string and not a list . The final value has to be "[var]" type: AnsibleUnicode (in your case); Another example: nimbus.seeds: '["111.222.333.44"]'

Comment: You're welcome, the problem is that you put brackets `[]` around a string. The solution is simple. Do not put brackets `[]` around a string. Another example: `nimbus: "111.222.333.44"`

Comment: Thanks, but I need them since the service I configure need those brackets :( I would like to not use them but they are mandatory

Comment: You're welcome. This is interesting. Update the question with the link to the details of the service.